# Auto Layout is enabled on storyboard but I am still getting AutolayoutMaskContraints

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to do a pure auto layout constraint based app, no autoresizing, and in my storyboard I turn on the flag "Use Auto Layout" in the Xcode 5 File Attributes for the Storyboard and yet I am still getting exceptions. I don't turn on translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints anywhere in the code. It is my understanding that IB will disable translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints if auto layout is turned on. Any ideas?

```
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xdca62c0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0xdca7310]-(201)-[UIView:0xcc69170]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xdca63e0 V:[UIView:0xcc69170]-(112)-[_UILayoutGuide:0xdc51f50]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xdc581e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0xdca7310(52)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xdc97780 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0xdca7310]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xdca7240 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xdc7e3b0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0xdc51f50(32)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xdc7df20 _UILayoutGuide:0xdc51f50.bottom == UIView:0xdca7240.bottom>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xdcce0c0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0xdca7240(320)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xdca62c0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0xdca7310]-(201)-[UIView:0xcc69170]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Is view 0xdca7240 created programmatically? `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` defaults to `YES` for programmatically created views.

Comment: **Most** views have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `NO` when created in IB with auto-layout on, but a container view, for example, does not. (Or rather, the embedded view that will be the container view.)

Comment: thanks Scott and Timothy. Pretty much wasted a day on this, but my answer below is what I determined.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the root view controller for a view has the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints turned on all the time. You can see this in the xml in the storyboard file. All the subviews however have the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints off. I suspect this is normal behavior, but a bit confusing if you are expecting no translations to occur.